# Алгоритм определения пересечения прямоугольников

Tags: алгоритм

Исходные данные: прямоугольники, заданные в виде массива элементов из x, y, w, h.
Требуется определить, есть ли пересечения хотя бы двух прямоугольников.

Текущая реализация - в лоб, циклом проходим все прямоугольники кроме последнего, и для каждого вложенным циклом проверяем пересечение с последующими. При первом пересечении оба цикла прерываются.

Есть ли более эффективный способ?

Касательно моего случая кол-во прямоугольников: >10000, среда выполнения: javascript в браузере.

Comment: нужно ли определить, какие именно прямоугольники пересеклись, или достаточно проверки наличия / отсутствия пересечения?

Comment: @Sergiks только факт наличия пересечения хотя бы двух

Comment: еще определитесь с краевым условием: если у двух прямоугольников только одна общая угловая точка – они пересекаются?

Comment: @Sergiks пересекаются, или может я упустил что-то, в каких ситуациях их можно принимать как не пересекающиеся?

Comment: может, нужна ненулевая площадь пересечения, когда от этого зависит «сила» пересечения

Comment: @Sergiks хотя о чем это я, конечно не пересекаются. Если площадь пересечения нулевая, считаем что не пересекаются.

Comment: related: [Collision detection (part 2): Box intersection](https://0fps.net/2015/01/18/collision-detection-part-2/)

Answer (score 6):

Задача строится поверх двух одномерных поисков наложения диапазонов.

Исходный массив мало полезен, надо привести к массивам только-координат, по два X и по два Y на прямоугольник. Пусть они всегда будут по возрастанию, X начала всегда меньше X конца прямоугольника.

На примере X. Два прямоугольника дали следующие иксы: `[3,7], [5,9]`. Эти значения надо как-то слить в один массив и отсортировать по возрастанию координаты, при этом сохранив их назначение – кто начало, а кто конец какого-то прямоугольника. Можно их привести к объектам типа:

```
[
  { x:3, io: 1, rect_id: 0 },
  { x:7, io:-1, rect_id: 0 },
  { x:5, io: 1, rect_id: 1 },
  { x:9, io:-1, rect_id: 1 },
]
```

и отсортировать по свойству `x`.

Далее останется двигаться от меньшего к большему и считать текущую сумму `io`. Пока нет пересечений, будет `0` или `1`. Как только начнется пересечение, появится значение `>1`. Это означает, что проекция прямоугольника, которому принадлежит текущая точка, на ось X накладывается с проекцией прямоугольника, которому принадлежит точка предыдущая.

Так найдутся пары (или компании побольше) кандидатов на пересечения по осям X и Y. И останется найти общие среди них.

Comment: Уточняю. По сути это метод вертикальной декомпозиции, но только его начальные шаги. Дальше надо бы использовать какое-нибудь дерево или ещё раз сортировку чтобы быстро проверять пересечения в группах. Но этот метод обычно решает значительно более сложную задачу - поиск общей площади. Для исходной задачи можно использовать алгоритм заметающей прямой http://e-maxx.ru/algo/intersecting_segments при этом,  т.к. все линии параллельны осям, алгоритм можно СУЩЕСТВЕННО упростить. А можно не упрощать, а просто скопировать реализацию. Сложности n log n должно хватить, хотя можно до n дожать вроде бы.